# why my application pwa does not work offline?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

an Angular 10 application with pwa with deployment via firebase hosting

(1) the application works online

(2) once the application is launched, I cut the internet and I can continue to browse between the pages

(3) once the application is launched, I cut off the internet.
I refresh the page (F5) and I come across: HTTP ERROR 504

(4) once the application is launched. I install the application. I run it via its icon. the application is working. I cut the internet. I relaunch the icon and
: HTTP ERROR 504

it is however possible to launch an application offline once installed or the page refreshes, is that right?

ngsw-config.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
  ],
...
```

have I forgotten something?

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the PWA registration strategy to register immediately so that it register immediately on the browser.

```
 ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { 
enabled: environment.production, registrationStrategy: "registerImmediately"  
})
```